# Area of triangle under tan conditions.

Tags: summation, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

For an acute triangle $ABC$, the following conditions hold.

$$\frac{1}{\tan A} + \frac{1}{\tan B} + \frac{1}{\tan C } =2$$

$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 =50 $$

Compute the area of such a triangle.

I used a tan addition law and get,
$$\tan A + \tan B + \tan C = \tan A \tan B \tan C $$.

And let $ \tan A \tan B \tan C = k $, so $\tan A , 
\tan B , \tan C $ are roots of the following cubic equation.
$x^3 - k x^2 +2k x - k $.
I am stuck right here.

Comment: Any  or ideas, please try to 

Comment: @five manifold Show please your attempts and I'll show my solution. Do it!

Comment: I used a tan addition law and get, $tan A + tan B + tan C = tanA tanB tanC $.
And let $ tan A tan B tan C = k $, so $tan A , tan B , tan C $ are roots of the following cubic equation.
$x^3 - k x^2 +2k x - k $. 
I am stuck right here..

Comment: Conditions of the problem are correct as above.

Comment: @five manifold I just made mistake. Sorry. I fixed. See now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $$2=\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab\cos\gamma}{ab\sin\gamma}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{4S}=\frac{50}{4S},$$ which gives $$S=\frac{25}{4}.$$

Comment: Good Idea!! It helps a lot.

Comment: @five manifold Good luck!

Comment: a small typo: $$2=\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab\cos\gamma}{ab\sin\gamma}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{4S}=\frac{50}{4S}$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會
  I fixed. Thank you!